# Reflector is undefined - three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to get a reflector surface in my scene. I used the chunk of code from the [webgl_mirror example.](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_mirror.html)

From what I can understand this is the only required code to place a reflective object in my scene:

```
var geometry = new THREE.CircleBufferGeometry( 40, 64 );
            var groundMirror = new Reflector( geometry, {
                clipBias: 0.003,
                textureWidth: WIDTH * window.devicePixelRatio,
                textureHeight: HEIGHT * window.devicePixelRatio,
                color: 0x777777,
                recursion: 1
            } );
            groundMirror.position.y = 0.5;
            groundMirror.rotateX( - Math.PI / 2 );
            scene.add( groundMirror );
```

This is how i'm calling each of my scripts in my HTML:

```
     <script
    type="text/javascript"
    src="index.js"

  ></script>


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheet.css">




      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/animejs@3.0.1/lib/anime.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/105/three.min.js"></script>
      <script src="Reflector.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/mrdoob/three.js@r92/examples/js/loaders/GLTFLoader.js"></script>






</head>
<body>
```

Reflector.js & index.js are in the root of my project at the moment.

I keep getting this error:

**Reflector is not defined at window.onload**

Answer (score 1):

Try putting your index.js `<script>` tag at the end of `<body>` so it gets executed last.

```html
<head>
    <script src=".../three.js"></script>
    <script src="Reflector.js"></script>
    <!-- ... all other dependency libraries -->
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Rest of your HTML body... -->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</body>
```

That way when you call `new Reflector()`, the required file is available to be used.

(As a side note, try using matching versions of GLTFLoader and Three.js. Using a loader that's `r92` with Three.js `r105` may lead to incompatibilities or errors.)

Comment: I tried this and I'm still getting the Reflector is undefined at window.onload

Comment: @Angelo Can you add the part of your code where you're using `window.onload`? Also, what does the top of your `Reflector.js` file look like? Does it start with `THREE.Reflector = function ` or is it `var Reflector = function `? You might be using the wrong file for your case.

Comment: apologies I took time from work and this aspect of my project got left behind. I'm going to try and implement again soon.